# Image URL not showing on API Call Strapi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, strapi

On scrapi I create two collection:

```
1: Content for a page
2: For Files
```

A file can Belong to multiple pages, when I call the api

```
GET http://localhost:3323/api/mypages/1?populate=*
```

Load everything including the file, but the file don't include all the fields.

ex

```
"File": {
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "attributes": {
            "name": myFiley",
            "expDate": "2023-07-07",
            "createdAt": "2023-06-15T19:09:36.841Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-06-15T22:08:28.997Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-06-15T19:20:30.630Z"
          }
        }
```

But if I call the file api I get all the details:

```
GET http://localhost:3323/api/files/1?populate=file
```

Is there a way to get all the file field on my first api call